# Crash in drawRect - what causes it?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Some of my users are getting this crash.

As far as I can tell, it's somehow connected to the `-drawRect:` method of my subclassed `NSTextView`, but I can't see what might cause it, and stress testing has failed to shake out the bug.

Code for drawRect

```
- (NSRange)visibleRangeOfTextView:(NSRect) rect {
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [self
                                      layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [self
                                      textContainer];
    NSRange glyphRange, characterRange;
    // first transform to text container coordinates
    NSPoint containerOrigin = [self textContainerOrigin];
    rect.origin.x -= containerOrigin.x;
    rect.origin.y -= containerOrigin.y;

    // next, compute glyph range
    glyphRange = [layoutManager glyphRangeForBoundingRect:rect inTextContainer:textContainer];

    // finally, compute character range
    characterRange = [layoutManager characterRangeForGlyphRange:glyphRange actualGlyphRange:NULL];
    return characterRange;
}

- (NSRect)rectForCharacterRange:(NSRange)charRange
{
    NSRect rect = [self
                   firstRectForCharacterRange:charRange];
    rect.origin = [[self window]
                   convertScreenToBase:rect.origin];
    rect = [self convertRect:rect fromView:nil];
    if (!rect.size.width) rect.size.width = 6.0;
    return rect;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSLog(@"Marking it");
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSRange visible = [self visibleRangeOfTextView:dirtyRect];
    NSRange last = NSMakeRange(visible.location, 0);    while (true) {
        NSRange error = [appController rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:self.string onlyInRange:visible startingAt:last.location + last.length];
        last = error;
        if (error.location == NSNotFound) {
            break;
        }
        [arr addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:error]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Spellchecked");

    [[NSColor redColor] setStroke];
    CGFloat dash[] = {2.0f, 2.0f} ;
    // Make the text ranges and mark them
    for (NSValue *val in arr) {
        NSRange range = [val rangeValue]; 
        NSRect rectInTextView = [self rectForCharacterRange:range];
        NSRect toDraw = rectInTextView;
        NSBezierPath*    aPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
        [aPath setLineDash:dash count:2 phase:0];

        NSPoint lineStart = toDraw.origin;
        lineStart.y += toDraw.size.height;
        NSPoint lineEnd = lineStart;
        lineEnd.x += toDraw.size.width;

        [aPath moveToPoint:lineStart];
        [aPath lineToPoint:lineEnd];
        [aPath stroke];        
    };
    NSLog(@"Done");    
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[5751]: garbage collection is ON
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteTextStorage attribute:atIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91387fc6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d4d7d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91387dfa +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91387d84 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   AppKit                              0x00000001005d842c -[NSConcreteTextStorage attribute:atIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:] + 131
    5   AppKit                              0x00000001006288ec -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:atPoint:parameters:] + 910
    6   AppKit                              0x00000001006277a2 -[NSTextView drawRect:] + 1913
    7   Skrivest√∏tte                       0x000000010000b56c Skrivest√∏tte + 46444
    8   AppKit                              0x0000000100626e66 -[NSTextView _drawRect:clip:] + 2545
    9   AppKit                              0x00000001004a985d -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 3020
    10  AppKit                              0x00000001004aa34e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5821
    11  AppKit                              0x00000001004aa34e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5821
    12  AppKit                              0x00000001004a39af -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 4755
    13  AppKit                              0x000000010049c395 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1528
    14  AppKit                              0x00000001004a1592 -[NSClipView _immediateScrollToPoint:] + 6533
    15  AppKit                              0x000000010049fb75 -[NSClipView scrollToPoint:] + 239
    16  AppKit                              0x000000010058f637 -[NSScrollView scrollClipView:toPoint:] + 266
    17  AppKit                              0x000000010058f3da -[NSClipView _scrollTo:animateScroll:flashScrollerKnobs:] + 1497
    18  AppKit                              0x00000001005923b7 -[NSClipView _scrollTo:animate:] + 27
    19  AppKit                              0x0000000100bcd5a2 __-[NSScrollView _snapRubberBand]_block_invoke_2 + 1536
    20  AppKit                              0x0000000100b3fc4e ____NSPeriodicInvokerScheduled_block_invoke_2 + 53
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff907b98ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff907bbc07 _dispatch_after_timer_callback + 16
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff907be2b6 _dispatch_source_invoke + 635
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff907baf77 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 71
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff907bb6f7 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 257
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9131d06c __CFRunLoopRun + 1724
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9131c676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93ab831f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93abf5c9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93abf456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    31  AppKit                              0x000000010045ff5d _DPSNextEvent + 659
    32  AppKit                              0x000000010045f861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    33  AppKit                              0x000000010045c19d -[NSApplication run] + 470
    34  AppKit                              0x00000001006dab88 NSApplicationMain + 867
    35  Skrivest√∏tte                       0x0000000100001020 Skrivest√∏tte + 4128
    36  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
```

Comment: Can you look at what's going on here:

35  Skrivest√∏tte                       0x0000000100001020 Skrivest√∏tte + 4128

Comment: Sorry, this is what I've got. I've had no luck symbolifying the crash report for some reason.

Comment: First try to pin down which of the used NSRanges causes the exception. Then check its values in case of the exception. Your code looks ok, so probably the reason for the invalid NSRange lies outside of it

Comment: tomk I think you may have nailed it. Similar code in my iOS app will at times detect a range that goes beyond the string in the txt view, causing a crash in the layout manager. I suspect it's the same thing here. An odd race condition really. Why don't you pose it as an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: The trace seems to indicate that the `[super drawRect:]` triggers this (i.e. `NSTextView` itself).  You said you subclass it...which methods exactly do you override?  Do you override anything that returns a range, such as `selectedRanges`?

Comment: Totally aside from the point, but you are leaking "arr".

Comment: @michael_mackenzie: Surely not leaking if I am using ARC?

Answer (score 1):

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***

> [NSConcreteTextStorage attribute:atIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'

It is clearly a NSRange exception, as O' y said

Comment: I think that the real cause is that the range goes beyond the length of the text in the text view, and so requesting the rectangle for it from the layout manager crashes. Still, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add assert function to check the "range"

```
NSRange range = [val rangeValue];
```

make sure range will not be `NSNotFound`.

Comment: While that can't hurt to add the assert, I'm pretty sure the code that populates arr screens out the NSNotFound items.