# My App getting crash when enter any special character in textfield in Objective-C (iOS: 15)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing below error while entering any special character in textfield.

iOS : 15
Language : Obj-C

[image]

```
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'out of bounds characterRange {0, 0} specified to _drawTexCorrectionMarker:characterRange:atOrigin:graphicsContext:'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Could you give part of the code? I don’t know if you noticed the error "out of bounds characterRange {0, 0}"

Comment: I don't know from where this error is located.

Comment: Have you tried breakpoint positioning?

Comment: Yes, but not traceable

Comment: My guess is that you have a problem with the rich text, and you need to analyze the specific code. I don't know if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757481/crash-in-drawrect-what-causes-it) will help you.

Comment: Yes, got the issue.

Comment: Is this your question here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693388 ?

Comment: It's due to UIColor.

Comment: Thank you all for the help

Comment: No stacktrace? No lore info in console? You don't have delegates methods for that UITextField? Is it programmatically created? By storyboard? What are its properties? Does this appear in all textfields?